# asp:DropDownList tripling results in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datatable

I'm using a DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and bind it with my database as in the code below:

```
 ddlCategory.DataSource = readCategory.Category();
 ddlCategory.DataTextField = readCategory.Category().Columns[1].ToString();
 ddlCategory.DataValueField = readCategory.Category().Columns[0].ToString();
 ddlCategory.DataBind();
```

My ddlCategory had to show this data: 'Microsoft', 'Apple', 'Google' but is showing it tripled.

readCategory is working perfectly.
In my database it isn't tripled.

What's going on? (If needed I can post more details)

Comment: how many records do you get when u run select * from tbl_category

Comment: 4 records ('Microsoft', 'Apple', 'Google' and 'Test').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is `readCategory.Category()`

```
public DataTable Category()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_category", conn);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

conn is my String Connection.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say "tripled" i'm guessing the calls to `Category()` are appending to a list of some sort.

Can you post the code in `readCategory.Category()`?